# Jupyter notebook is not running [PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user]

Tags: command-line, software-installation, jupyter

I have tried to uninstall jupyter notebook using the command `pip uninstall jupyter_core` and installed it again but it didn't work. Also tried this command `pip-autoremove jupyter -y` and installed it again also didn't work. Also uninstalled it and tried this command to remove the cache from the snapd folder `sudo sh -c 'rm -rf /var/lib/snapd/cache/*'` didn't work again.

I have tried my best please help me

```
abuhaithem@abuhaithem:~$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 645, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'runtime_dir'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 269, in launch_instance
    return super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 981, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 110, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2147, in initialize
    self.init_configurables()
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1649, in init_configurables
    connection_dir=self.runtime_dir,
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 686, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 648, in get
    default = obj.trait_defaults(self.name)
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1752, in trait_defaults
    return self._get_trait_default_generator(names[0])(self)
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 106, in _runtime_dir_default
    ensure_dir_exists(rd, mode=0o700)
  File "/home/abuhaithem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_core/utils/__init__.py", line 12, in ensure_dir_exists
    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer
**1**. first open your terminal and uninstall the jupyter notebook
`pip uninstall jupyter_core`
**2**. after that type the following
`ls -a`
**3**. after that delete the .cache folder
`rm -r .cache`
**4**. and also delete this folder
`rm -r .pam_environment`
**5**. after this all steps finally reinstall the jupyter notebook again
`pip install notebook`